# Can we add functionality to OpenShift default UI

Tags: openshift

Can we display the pods from all projects on a single page?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: If you're using 3.11, you can use the Cluster Console to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can display `pods` per `project` on the `GUI` (`web console`, `grafana`, `cluster/application` console).

Using CLI is as follows for diplaying all pods from all projects.

```
# oc get pod --all-namespaces
```

Comment: Using CLI we can do, however, I want to know if we can change the existing Openshift UI to add new features, like seeing all the pods of all projects in a single page without having to change the project.

Comment: It look like big custom to me. You can custom for web console as [Customizing the Web Console](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/web_console_customization.html).